# Rails 4 - helper method not responding to if condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I'm trying to figure out how to use a helper method in rails 4.

I have profile show page - if the current user is looking at:
-  their own profile page, they should have a menu with 6 options on that page (each option links to the visible bits of that user's profile); or else
- another user's profile page, they should have a menu with 4 options on that page (each option links to a the visible bits of that other user's profile).

In my helper folder, I have a profiles_helper.rb:

```
module ProfilesHelper

def items_for_profile_menu(profile)
        if current_user.id = @profile.user_id 
      "<li class='col-xs-4 col-sm-2 nopadding menuitem' style='background:#006F7F'>
               <a href='index.html' class='hvr-sweep-to-bottom'>
                      <br><br>
                      <span>Dashboard</span>
               </a>
        </li>"
    else
 "<li class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 nopadding menuitem blue'>
       <a href='resume.html' class='hvr-sweep-to-bottom'>
       <i class='flaticon-graduation61'>
       </i><span>Researh History</span></a>
   </li>"
```

In my profile show, I have:

```
<ul id="nav" class="row nopadding cd-side-navigation">
   <%= raw (items_for_profile_menu(@profile)) %>   
</ul>
```

When I save all this and try it - I get the same 6 item menu when I am logged in as the owner of the profile, as I do when I look at the profile from another account.

How do I get this helper method to distinguish between the current user who's id is the same as the profile.user_id that is for the displayed profile and the current user's own profile page?

My model associations are:

User:

```
has_one :profile
```

Profile:

```
belongs_to :user
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend mixing view code into the helper. Simplify the helper (e.g. `def this_user?`) to just determine if the output should be shown. Then use `<% if this_user? %>template if logged in<% else %>template if logged out<% end %>`

Comment: @Owen - what happens if the other user also happens to be logged in? I only want to show the full menu to the user that owns the profile.

Comment: Also - did you mean `@profile` or `profile` (as the latter is passed as a parameter to the helper)?

Comment: Owen - I don't understand. In the show page, I want to show the menu items based on whether the user is the profile owner or a profile visitor. I think @profile is correct in that context because I want to give it the profile page being visited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is using assignment instead of comparison.

```
if current_user.id = @profile.user_id
```

should read

```
if current_user.id == profile.user_id
```

However, while we're looking at this, you should consider separating the view code from application logic. All of the code to output the HTML should be in the view if possible. So your helper should be simplified, example as follows:

```
module ProfilesHelper
  def logged_in_as?(profile)
    current_user.id == profile.user_id
  end
end
```

Then your profile show can be:

```
<ul id="nav" class="row nopadding cd-side-navigation">
  <% if logged_in_as?(@profile) %>
    <li class='col-xs-4 col-sm-2 nopadding menuitem' style='background:#006F7F'>
      <a href='index.html' class='hvr-sweep-to-bottom'>
        <br><br>
        <span>Dashboard</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  <% else %>
    <li class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 nopadding menuitem blue'>
      <a href='resume.html' class='hvr-sweep-to-bottom'>
        <i class='flaticon-graduation61'>
        </i><span>Researh History</span></a>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

This way the HTML is all together and you don't need to mess around with your helper when you want to change it - plus, you can reuse it elsewhere for simple logic in other templates.

Comment: Thank you  - that works. I'll accept when the timer allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with owen in this case that don't need create html recursive. I think is better is not abstract of the view.

#### profiles_Helper.rb

```
module ProfilesHelper

  def is_current_user?(profile)
     current_user == profile.user
  end

end
```

#### views/xxx.html.erb

```
<%- if is_current_user?(@profile) %>
  <li class='col-xs-4 col-sm-2 nopadding menuitem' style='background:#006F7F'>
    <a href='index.html' class='hvr-sweep-to-bottom'>
      <br><br>
      <span>Dashboard</span>
    </a>
  </li>"
<% else %>
  <li class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 nopadding menuitem blue'>
    <a href='resume.html' class='hvr-sweep-to-bottom'>
      <i class='flaticon-graduation61'>
      </i><span>Researh History</span>
    </a>
 </li>"
<% end %>
```

Comment: only after submit this post that I saw the answer of Owen.

Comment: Your code still has the unintended assignment operator.